# Django timezone is wrong

Tags: django, timezone

I can't seem to make timezone works with Django 1.11.

My Settings.py:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

I'm starting the server at :

[image: utc]

And it outputs the following:

[image: server time]

Which is 4:09PM

And of course when doing:

```
form django.utils import timezone
today = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
print(today)
```

The outuput is also wrong by +1 hour, while the time is indeed specified as +00:

> 2017-08-10 16:09:04.208536+00:00

Any idea of what i'm missing ?

Comment: It is taking local time from your machine.

Comment: Nop, I'm currently in France with DST so UTC +2